# Whats the correct procedure for sanitizing a Solid State Drive?

Tags: solid-state-drive

SSD's being an entirely different kettle of fish from regular mechanical hard drivers, what is the correct procedure for sanitizing one, assuming that I want to re-use it. Waist not, want not.

It's a Corsair SSD.

Comment: If the goal is to "erase" the SSD, use the trim command to mark all sectors as "deleted", which is normally used to aid in the repacking of data in the SS memory. Then rewrite all sectors, perhaps with zeros, then use trim command again to mark all sectors as deleted. In the case of an operating system that incorporates trim commands, I'm wondering if doing a quick format followed by writing large files to fill the SSD then deleting all the files would be good enough.

Comment: The goal is to erase the empty space of a newly encrypted drive.

Comment: The drive doesn't know about "empty" space unless a trim command is used to note which sectors have been deleted. Even then, I don't know if there is a command to then force the SSD to go through a full repack of "non-empty" data, and then an "erase" cycle for all the "empty" space.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62253/what-is-the-difference-between-ata-secure-erase-and-security-erase-how-can-i-en

Comment: Well right now, I'm using the Nautilus "Wipe Available Space" option from the drop-down menu to erase a mechanical HD.  Does it also properly handle SSDs? This must be related to the secure-delete package and/or the nautilus-wipe package.

Comment: https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase

Comment: i just saw your `goal is to erase empty space of newly encrypted drive`  Not sure what you are trying to accomplish - if the free space is encrypted then why does it matter?  If free space for some reason lies outside the encrypted partition then why?

Comment: That's the problem. Free space is free space. It isn't encrypted because there isn't anything there.

Comment: you may want to re-word your post which gives the distinct impression you are looking to sanitize i.e. wipe an entire SSD.  If you are looking specifically to wipe free space of an SSD while preserving existing data on it then that's a different animal.  Off top of my head there's BCWipe, and CCleaner has a wipe free space option - whether these work on SSD's I don't know.  This is assuming it's a consumer grade SSD, and not something like an Intel 520 SSD's that does full SSD hardware encrypting.  You also may want to indicate the model SSD you want to accomplish this on.

Comment: but the more I think about wiping free space on an SSD,  that is inherently accomplished by the TRIM feature.  Per many articles about TRIM you can easily find from reputable sources:  `One of the more overlooked aspects of TRIM, as amazing and helpful as the command is, is that once it’s issued, your chance of data recovery has essentially gone to 0.`

Comment: For ssd it becomes quite simple to wipe free space because SSD's are NAND flash memory and TRIM forces everything marked as deleted to 0... more for the purpose of performance and the secure erase just happens inherently because of TRIM.  Can be a bonus if you are security minded, or a downside if you need to recover accidentally deleted file.  you can verify this by searching about `data recovery ssd trim` and it also matters how the ssd is used: standalone where trim is enabled vs in RAID or NAS where it is likely to be disabled.

Comment: @ron So you are telling me that no action is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is marked as an answer, I would caution anyone to first understand TRIM and how it may or **may not** be applied for your application with regards to the hardware, and software within your operating system, and understand the capabilities of a given SSD (make/model/firmware) with regards to TRIM.

no action required **only if** TRIM is enabled and working as expected on a single SSD connected directly via SATA & AHCI as a single drive.  This is for wiping free space, it **eventually** happens inherently in the background.

If you look up the definition of TRIM it forces all blocks of memory to zero that have been marked as deleted- which is why so many articles talk about `how it's impossible to recover data on SSD with TRIM`.

**But beware** this may not apply to SSD's used in storage devices such as a NAS or in RAID where TRIM might be disabled or managed by the hardware. Again search on `data recovery TRIM` and read articles from reputable sources, and make sure you recognize how you are using your ssd.  Obviously if you are really concerned about this you should also verify data can't be recovered using a data recovery tool.

**Also beware** that when you delete a file and empty the trash bin, that TRIM may not happen immediately after the delete.  If enabled we only know TRIM will eventually happen, which is why if you are really concerned about wiping free space you should understand how to manually force TRIM to happen.

the article "TRIMcheck: Does Your SSD Really have TRIM Working?" dated Feb. 24, 2013 at http://www.thessdreview.com/daily-news/latest-buzz/trimcheck-does-your-ssd-really-have-trim-working/
describes the issue rather well.

if you are interested in **sanitizing a SSD** as in wiping the entire drive then the best method in my opinion is performing an **ATA secure erase** on the drive, ideally with a toolkit provided by the manufacturer of the SSD and following their instructions which will be supported by the SSD's firmware and actually work.

For the Corsair SSD in question, there is the `Corsair SSD Toolbox` which can be downloaded from the corsair website.

For any other SSD make, such as samsung, search on `secure erase samsung`.

Comment: Corsair SSD Toolbox is useless. Doesn't work with Linux.

Comment: so in linux you want `fstrim`  answered here -->   http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218076/ssd-how-often-should-i-do-fstrim